# How to create a Principal object in a customAuthenticationProvider?

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security

I have a web-app and I´m using spring security. I had this configuration for the authentication provider in the securityContext.xml:

```
<authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder hash="sha-256" />
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="<the query>"

            authorities-by-username-query="<the other query>" />
</authentication-provider>
```

This is working fine. Now I want to have the authentication in a customAuthentication provider in a java class. Something like:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        //I check the username-password, and grantedAuths       

        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, grantedAuths);

        return auth;

        else //it enters here with an incorrect username-password (the if is in the original code) 
        {
            return null;
        }

}
```

Now, the authentication works fine. An incorrect username-password with not let you log in and a correct one will. The problem is, I use the Principal object in the app, and I am getting errors like

```
Invalid property 'principal.username' of bean class [org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken]:
```

Why the customAuthenticationProvider is not creating the Principal object? (I think this is the problem) and How can I create it (the Principal object)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        String name = authentication.getPrincipal();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        //I check the username-password, and grantedAuths       

        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, grantedAuths);

        return auth;

        else //it enters here with an incorrect username-password (the if is in the original code) 
        {
            return null;
        }

}
```

Comment: I have already tried that, with the sameresults. I found a different solution though, I found that the principal is created, but not as a User object (like I was using before) but just as a string. I used this string and worked for me.